# Application that is able to resume failed download

Tags: applications, downloading

It's often happening when I want to download a file with `browser` that download fails due to a bad connection and then I have to download a file from the beginning.

Is there an app or browser plugin that is able to continue downloading of failed download?

I found only `byte tornado` app which is not much help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for, but if you have installed busybox and a terminal application, you can continue your download with:

```
wget --continue --output-document file.part URL
```

Comment: I tried `bosybox` but it needs the phone to be rooted. I'm not so advanced user yet and I heard that with rooted device warranty is lost.

Comment: You can also [install busybox without rooting your phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.busybox).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an android device try HTTP Downloader. It can be used to request download from any byte offset. So that you can skip how much you have already downloaded & complete the remaining.

After completing, you can join those 2 file parts to get the full completed file. (File joiner is inbuilt in the app. Also they provide free File joiner application for PC)

Here are the links

App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ajk.http.downloader

Step wise instructions: https://youtu.be/lI4hm0NuosQ

**Note**: I  am affiliated with the developer Resonance which developed that app and the video.